# How to get or set the keys for non-anonymous azure functions on Kubernetes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks

I'm deploying the default Python templated httpTrigger Azure Function to Kubernetes (AKS) with this command

`func kubernetes deploy --name test --registry testfunctionregistry.azurecr.io`

When my configuration sets authLevel to anonymous like so

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can call the function just fine, but if I use `function` as the `authLevel` I get a 401 which I think indicates I need to pass as valid `code` url parameter or auth code header.

However, it's not clear how to get a key for this for functions deployed to Kubernetes - the docs all refer to the Azure Function Apps Portal UI for this, but that's not used when I'm deploying to Kubernetes.

How do I find or set the key?

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed ElSayed from the functions team has shared how this can be done on kubernetes [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4147#issuecomment-477442831).

For reference, one would first have to create a `Secret` like the following. A `host.json` for the master key and individual `<function-name>.json` for each function.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: azure-functions-secrets
type: Opaque
stringData:
  host.json: |-
    {
      "masterKey": {
        "name": "master",
        "value": "MASTER_KEY",
        "encrypted": false
      },
      "functionKeys": [ ]
    }
  httptrigger.json: |-
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "name": "default",
          "value": "A_FUNCTION_KEY",
          "encrypted": false
        }
      ]
    }
```

Then in your deployment, mount the secret as a volume to the functions container like this

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: {azure-functions-container-name}
    image: {your-container-image}
    volumeMounts:
    - name: secrets
      mountPath: "/azure-functions-host/Secrets"
      readOnly: true
    env:
    - name: AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType
      value: files
  volumes:
  - name: secrets
    secret:
      secretName: azure-functions-secrets
```

Comment: This is great, but how do I use a custom spec in my deployment? I'm just using `func kubernetes deploy` and I don't get to interact with the yaml